# Why is Taskmaster called Taskmaster?

Tags: marvel, the-taskmaster

Taskmaster is a Marvel character who can replicate any physical action he sees, as long as it does not require any superhuman abilities. I have researched all over the place, but I cannot find out where Taskmaster's name came from. Where did he get his name?

Answer (score 29):

I don't know of any explicit canon reason given for his name but I may as well turn my comment into an answer. Taskmaster's real name is **T**ony (Anthony really but everyone calls him Tony like Stark) **Masters**. On top of that his power is photographic reflexes, or that he can watch someone do something and be able to copy them instinctively, up to a point: no superpowers really and there's a limit before he forgets some things. However, this power essentially means he can **master** any **task**.

His real name combined with his power and Taskmaster seems kind of apt to me.

Thanks to Valorum we also see a Deadpool card in *The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl Vol. 2* Issue 15. and Deadpool gives the origin for the name as what I have given above.

> This dude can "master" any "task", just by seeing it performed! Oh that's where his name comes from, ha ha I just realised that, cool
>
> [...]
>
> **Deadpool:** This guy can master some friggin' tasks, I'll tell you what!

[image: Close up on the Taskmaster card, relevant sections quoted above]
<sub>*Click for the full page.*</sub>

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that "taskmaster" is an uncommon English word meaning "someone who gives you a lot of work."  (The word is [more prominent in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskmaster_(TV_series)), though.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The only context I've ever heard "taskmaster" used was in the Bible. E.g. [Exodus 1:11](https://biblehub.com/exodus/1-11.htm), [Exodus 5:6](https://biblehub.com/exodus/5-6.htm) (though in fact those two uses of English "taskmaster" are translated from different Hebrew words). Also [other places in the Bible](https://biblescan.com/search.php?q=taskmaster), but again, Exodus is the only context I have heard it discussed (pre-teen Hebrew school classes).

Comment: @RossPresser The term 'harsh taskmaster' is actually used somewhat commonly in English.